# Parsing/extracting information from JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying to extract (timestamp, value) tuples from this third party JSON message:

```
{
    "data": {
        "1496845320000": [
            0.14
        ],
        "1496845380000": [
            0.14
        ],
        "1496845560000": [
            0.14
        ],
        "1497013740000": [
            "undef"
        ],
        "1497013800000": [
            "undef"
        ],
        "1497013860000": [
            "undef"
        ]
    },
    "status": "ok"
}
```

This is how I'm extracting the JSON entity:

```
val batchReadings = http.singleRequest(httpRequest) map {
  case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) =>
    entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _).foreach { body =>
      JSON.parseFull(body.utf8String) match {
        case Some(e: Map[String, Any]) =>
          e.get("status") match {
            case Some("ok") => println("ok!")
              e.get("data") match {
                case Some(f: Map[String, List[Any]]) =>
                  println("entered second case")
                  new EfergyReadingsData(f.toList).getReadings
              }
            case _ => log.info("EfergyReaderWorkerActor: Received unknown message\n" + body.utf8String)
          }
      }

    }
  case HttpResponse(code, _, entity, _) =>
    //entity.toStrict(100, materializer)   N.B. Not having this, will freeze after 4 calls!
    s"Response code: $code"
  case unknown =>
    s"unknown response: $unknown"
}
```

And this is the EfergyReadingsData class:

```
class EfergyReadingsData(readings: List[(String, List[Any])]) {
  def getReadings: List[(Long, Double)] = {
    println(readings)
    //    List((1123, 34.4))
    val filteredReadings = readings filter {
      f =>
      f._2 match {
        case  t:List[Any] =>
          t.head match {
            case Double => true
            case _ => false
          }
      }
    }
    val theRead = filteredReadings map {
      p => (p._1.toLong, p._2.head)
    }
    println(theRead)
    List((1123, 34.4))
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm not returning the List of tuples that I'm supposed to in `getReadings`, I just created a list to be returned so I could test the code.

Besides not being able to filter the list to remove only the `undef`entries (the `filteredReadings` is empty), the first obvious problem with this approach is that I'm pattern matching for types inside List and Map and therefore getting a warning about those being unchecked because they are eliminated by erasure.

Although not represented above for simplicity, I tried to mitigate this by using case classes for the Lists:

```
sealed abstract class AnyReading {
  val value: List[Any]
}

case class SuccessfulReading(override val value: List[Double]) extends AnyReading

case class FailedReading(override val value: List[String]) extends AnyReading
```

So, to conclude, what is the best way to go about this? I also thought of creating few case classes to represent the the JSON structure and try to deserialise the JSON message and then filter to remove the `undef` values, and ultimately get the list of tuples I wanted.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: can you use third party JSON parsing solutions? Like [play-json](https://github.com/playframework/play-json) for example?

Comment: Yes, I'm using io.spray.spray-json in other parts of the project, but i'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Take a quick look at the [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) docs.  I think it should be possible to define an implicit instance of `Reads[YourCaseClass]` that describes how to parse the JSON. With this implicit defined you can them read the JSON using `Json.fromJson` function.  Perhaps `spray-json` does something similar?

Comment: Yes, `spray-json` does the same thing. I'll try this later today with spray-json but I'm worried I'l end up with another issue, because the timestamp for the readings are the field name instead of a value. So I have no way to create a case class with a field with same name.

**Edit:** Example: a field named `1496845320000` would obviously not work for every other timestamp.